# Can I use Sass to apply a style to an element based on the presence of an attribute on another element?

Tags: css, sass

How can I use Sass to detect whether a style attribute is present on an element, and then apply a style to another element if so? Here's an outline of my problem:

Every site has a header that contains a logo and buttons. Some pages have a logo with a 60px height whilst others have a logo with a 40px height. When the logo is 60px high, the buttons need margin-top: 1rem added to them to vertically centre them within the header container. I know this isn't the only method I could use to vertically align these buttons in the middle.

Each site has a site-specific style sheet where the logo's height is declared. There are more general styles in other sass files that are included in this document. I'm trying to use Sass to create a rule that will apply the margin to the buttons only when the logo is 60px. I'm not sure whether this is possible with Sass.

Here is the simplified mark-up:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="grid-12">
            <div class="logoWrapper">
                <h1>
                    <a> </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="loginBox">
                <div class="loginTab">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the simplified CSS with the height inside a media query:

```
.logoWrapper {
    a {
        height: 3rem;
        @include bp(720) {
            height: 6rem;
        }
    }
}
```

The height is applied to the anchor tag within .logoWrapper. The margin needs to be added to .loginTab and three other elements just like it. I understand that I need to use a control directive like if() or @if to test for the condition, namely, the height of .logoWrapper's anchor tag, but I don't know how to express this and whether what I've tried is not working because the syntax is wrong or because the language doesn't have this capability.

I have tried to target the CSS attribute selector in various ways, to no avail. Here's an example of one attempt:

```
#loginBox {
    .loginTab {
        @include bp(720) {
            @if .logoWrapper a[height="6rem"] {
                margin-top: 1rem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps there's a way to harness the fact that #loginBox is a sibling of .logoWrapper?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that if style attribute is added to `.logoWrapper` element.
But as I can see, it isn't, and there is no style attribute. Height is defined in css.

There is no way to style something in css (or sass) depending on properties defined on some other element in css.

Here is example how this could be done if there is style attribute on `.logoWrapper` element

```
<div class="logoWrapper" style="height: 6em">
  <h1>
    <a></a>
  </h1>
</div>
<div id="loginBox"></div>


.logoWrapper[style="height: 6em"] + #loginBox {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. That doesn't seem to work though. But it's useful to know that what I was trying to do with CSS isn't actually possible. I'll have to implement this another way.